# THREE.js setting global position of Mesh causes jittering artifact

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to set the global position of an object, so I wrote a function `moveToPoint` which takes in a world point `x y z`, converts it into the local coordinate system, and updates the `object.position` to go to that new local coordinate.

But, when I call this function in the animation loop, I get an unusual jittering artifact. I'm not quite sure why this could happen since the code is deceptively simple.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32);
const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
sphere.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(sphere)


camera.position.z = 5;


function moveToPosition(object, x, y, z) {
  const pos = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
  object.worldToLocal(pos);
  object.position.copy(pos);
}


function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  moveToPosition(sphere, 0, 1, 0);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically toggling the Y-position from 0 to 1 to 0 to 1 to 0, etc...

Let's take it frame-by-frame

Frame 1:

- starting sphere position: `0, 0, 0`
- worldToLocal() sets `pos` to `0, 1, 0`
- ending sphere position: `0, 1, 0`

Frame 2:

- starting sphere position: `0, 1, 0`
- worldToLocal() sets `pos` to `0, 0, 0`
- ending sphere position: `0, 0, 0`

... and so on

Another way to look at it:

- Frame1: `[0, 0, 0].worldToLocal([0, 1, 0]) = [0, 1, 0]`
- Frame2: `[0, 1, 0].worldToLocal([0, 1, 0]) = [0, 0, 0]`

**Solution:**

Since the sphere isn't nested within any other objects, you can skip the `worldToLocal()` call. You typically only need this when you're dealing with nested objects, not when they're directly added to the scene.

I created a simple sin-wave animation from -1 to +1 to demonstrate:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 32, 32);
const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
sphere.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(sphere)

var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 2 );
scene.add( axesHelper );

camera.position.z = 5;


function moveToPosition(object, x, y, z) {
  const pos = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
  //object.worldToLocal(pos);
  object.position.copy(pos);
}


function animate(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  // Sin movement from -1 to +1
  const yPos = Math.sin(t / 1000);
  moveToPosition(sphere, 0, yPos, 0);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Why isn't `worldToLocal` setting pos to `0, 0, 0` in Frame 1? If the world coordinate system and local coordinate system coincide like you said, then shouldn't the origin be the same in both coordinate systems?